# if value present in specific XML node

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

i got a simple question that i just cant seem to figure out...
i have this xml file

```
<allroles>
  <role name ="Warehouse">
   <user>naim</user>
    <user>inbar</user>
  </role>
  <role name ="office">
    <user>pete</user>    

</role>
</allroles>
```

for some reason i am having trouble generating a VB code to find for example is naim in warehouse?

please help me.. i know this is simple but it is just eluding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var naimElem = XDocument.Load(xmlString)
    .Descendants("user")
    .Where(elem => elem.Value == "naim")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If it finds one that meets the criteria it will return the element; otherwise null.